# Second level key as types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a type as a second level key for a given object. So for example, for object:

```js
const myObj = {
  vegetabes: {
    legumes: ['chickpea', 'garbanzo', 'lentil'],
    tubers: ['potatoe', 'carrot']
  },
  meat: {
    farm: ['cow', 'goat', 'lamb'],
    wild: ['deer', 'bear']
  }
}
```

and function

```js
const findRecipe = (firstLevelKey: keyof typeof myObj, secondLevelKey: ?????) => {
   const collection = myObj[firstLevelKey][secondLevelKey]
   ...
}
```

What type should I give `secondLevelKey` so that it is restricted to the keys inside the selected `firstLevelKey`? Ex: if I call `findRecipe('vegetabes', ...)` the only valid values for the second argument would be `legumes` and `tubers`. If that's not possible, it could be enough to restrict to any of the second level keys `legumes`, `tubers`, `farm` and `wild`. But the ideal would be to restrict based on the 1st key.

If anyone knows how to get this to work on a generic function `<T>(firstLevelKey: keyof T, secondLevelKey: ?????) => {...}` that would be nice too. But the important part would be what's described in the previous paragraph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably would want to introduce a generic to ensure the keys are related correctly:

```
const findRecipe = <T extends keyof typeof myObj>(
  firstLevelKey: T,
  secondLevelKey: keyof typeof myObj[T]) => {
   const collection = myObj[firstLevelKey][secondLevelKey]
}
```

The fully generic version would be this:

```
function genericAccess<T, K extends keyof T>(
  instance: T,
  firstLevelKey: K,
  secondLevelKey: keyof T[K]
) {
   const item = instance[firstLevelKey][secondLevelKey];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeAoGGANwFMBzEqAQxRIgC5cDCYAbcgVzjsYG0ByYAAsAlsADWABxJV+AGhj8yVAE4oqYAF4h5i9mCgjW-ALpzmhKB1oqGMAZJDUoIErsGqVT08wC+5wm4qKEZ8FhgAM1U4PkEQAHd3MhBg91YqOBRTAJZ4owATWPySEhV3WlUfQl88GtBIWAiRMHyAJRJgEWksGAAeABUYEgAPKBIWiBhxEgQQCJgoBGk5+GR0AD4ACmYm2ygAGRJSVgBpGcZ+nIgO8HzD47OERmnZ+cXl+cRUNF5+kwBKLDrJgserQGCgVjsYCGcA9L7oXi7aD3EinGYmXjXep3I5ox4mWp4PBNFrtTrSTb8UgUai0CBpTjcBn-EnNNodLokKk0yg0OjuPKsfL8VmkjkU7n8IJQQUFUXEkkcMAwkRwihgUpiACCwGAdAgAwUJyGo3G+UmLxW-S2zGa0A0+ouOWRBzx6KeMBOVxuLVRHueM2tvBOhMBYUIYNgIjGcB69uoKpISJEe39BKxvtxDwxAG4iXgNVrgLr9RAIJsEWgFNTyHz6YyyFwBayiyodXqDZW1tXFLy6QKa0KRa3xsXS12qzWZXLhQqgA)