# Typescript function to get nested fields of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a function with typings that can retrieve values from a nested object.

Using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165619/second-level-key-as-types) I was able to get the typing to work for two levels. However, when I put a third (known) level between the two levels I am defining in my function parameters I get a typescript error. The code below will explain this better.

```
const fields = {
  field_yesno: {
    label: 'Select yes or no',
    options: {
      yes: {
        value: 'yes',
        label: 'Yes',
      },
      no: {
        value: 'no',
        label: 'No',
      }
    }
  },
  field_number: {
    label: 'Select one or two',
    options: {
      one: {
        value: 'one',
        label: 'One',
      },
      two: {
        value: 'two',
        label: 'Two',
      }
    }
  }
}

type FieldsType = typeof fields

export const getOptionLabel = <T extends keyof FieldsType>(
  field: T,
  value: keyof FieldsType[T]['options']) => {
  return fields[field].options[value].label as string
}

console.log(getOptionValue('field_number', ''))
```

I get the error

```
Type 'keyof...' cannot be used to index type ....
```

here

```
return fields[field].options[value].label as string
```

The crazy thing is IntelliSense works perfectly but I am still getting a typescript error

I have put together a [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwKYBsAmEYF4YG8CwAUDPMugPoCeSEYIAXHkSSSgIYBGqjA5AMqokwWNUwgATjDo8ANMxYgADlATgIjAsRYlRG+dpIA3NigCuSXqNn6D7Lil4BNGta3aAvnLcs6e79uMzCxgeaS8DFjtuEIA5EFcI9xskrU95RFQ0cjBTAFsucT9tKIcQgRQhWHAkGAkYKAB3ePCFZVVIIoNqzojA815qhIiYEt4AeTAkIY8W7UaGJn8WPuCeeenbTmieABUmjZIUj3kUlKIoSkUagDEyDB3LmpwLq5A4UkyIIiIkAA9FCSwUCQWAAcyQUDGbXAABktihsDAADw7GB-KBIMAYGAAayQlDeMFunweVwAfAAKdJ3Rg7ForRh4gnvYnoCCkpAAbR2AF1OTwlCo1DweQBKbBkxYkcQQ0ziMAfNmcjLoHkAOkF7QgnJW6pKMDYmGg4gQYFBRDOhGBEBAFTVKBAoIp4Mh0LAcPsFJ4KqyOXySHEshCPFFoqAA) demonstrating the issue.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: This is more or less the same issue as in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended fix is a particular sort of refactoring as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If I do that refactoring here I get the code in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKPVgw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you @jcalz. Yes, that does address the question. I think I followed most of your playground. I need to learn a bit more about `Record<>`. If you do write an answer up, love to know which one we should use between that and the other answer, which seems simpler? I am learning TS and reading a number of your answers on here have been very helpful. Thanks so much for taking the time.

Comment: [`Record<K, V>`](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) is just a utility type meaning "on object with keys of type `K` and values of type `V` at those keys".

Comment: ... Which answer you "should" use depends on your use case.  Are you trying to get the compiler to verify what you're doing is safe? Then you should use the refactoring I suggest.  Are you trying to just suppress the error and move on? Then you should use whatever type assertion lets you do that, such as the one given in the existing answer.  I usually write, uh, *long* answers, though, so I'm not inclined to write a whole answer if you're going to accept the other one.

Comment: @jcalz I am interested in learning what correct. Ultimately, I am moving my repos to TS so that I can ensure I have type safe code. I am trying to understand how Typescript works and why and happy to accept the answer that is the "right" way of doing it. Haha I have seen your answers, and grateful for a few of them that have helped me understand some TS nuances. But no expectation to provide an answer, I am grateful for the playground.

Comment: Hmm I'm still not sure how to tell you what is "correct".  Do you mean *verified as type safe by the compiler* or do you mean *idiomatic coding style*?  Those are unfortunately different here.

Answer (score 2):

You can work around the TS disappointment here with an explicit cast in the function:

```js
export const getOptionLabel =
  <T extends keyof FieldsType,
   Option extends keyof FieldsType[T]["options"]>
    (field: T, value: Option) => {
      const options = fields[field].options as Record<Option, { label: string }>;
      return options[value].label;
    }
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mA8j1N)

You can do it without the extra generic parameter or the temporary assignment, but these clarify what's going on.

Comment: I don't like this solution but I have been trying for a very long time to come up with an answer to this lol

Comment: @RobertRendell I was well and truly nerdsniped too